# MongoDB: How to merge original record back after lookup

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collections which I am using a `$lookup` to bring together:

```json
{
  "organizations": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "users": [1,2]
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "bar",
        "users": [1]
      }
  ],
  "users": [
      {
          "_id": 1,
          "name": "john1 smith"
      },
      {
          "_id": 2,
          "name": "bob johnson"
      }
  ]
}
```

The query works fine:

```json
[{
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "users",
                "localField": "users",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "members"
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$members"
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "original": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
                "members": {
                    "$push": "$members"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

however, the resulting `organizations` records don't return all of their properties without adding the `original` prop which gives me back a nesting of the original `organization`:

```json
{
        "_id": 1,
        "original": {
            "_id": 1,
            "name": "foo",
            "users": [
                1,
                2
            ],
            "members": {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "john1 smith"
            }
        },
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "john1 smith"
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "bob johnson"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm trying to get everything in the `original` prop back into the root along with the new `members` array.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I'm trying to get everything in the `original` object into the root so the object root props become `_id`, `name`, `users`, `members`

Comment: If you do lookup only, everything will be in root. I dont understand why do you do unwind and group!!

Comment: @varman I think I may have messed something up originally and went down the path of thinking my originally query didn't work. Thank you.